# Pytorch network not training

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train an activity recognition system using PyTorch, but the network is not training and loss is not dropping, even though I have a similar model working perfectly on keras. I have provided code for the training loop, model class, and dataset class here. Can you help me why the loss is not dropping (accuracy is not increasing)

main training loop

```py
# create dataset
dataset = IMU_dataset()


train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset,
                          batch_size=40,
                          shuffle=True,
                          num_workers=2)


num_epochs = 100
total_samples = len(dataset)
n_iterations = math.ceil(total_samples/4)
print(total_samples, n_iterations)
input_shape = 3
output_index = 6
device = torch.device('cpu')
model = HARmodel(input_shape, output_index).to(device)
model.float()
# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1) 
 
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # origin shape: [40, 3, 400]
        labels = labels.to(device)
        
        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs.to(device).float())
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.long())
        
        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
#         if (i+1) % 5 == 0:
#             print(f'loss: {loss.item()}')
    print(model.calculate_accuracy(dataset.x_data, dataset.y_data), model.calculate_loss(dataset.x_data, dataset.y_data, criterion))
```

Here is the model class.

```py
class HARmodel(nn.Module):
    """Model for human-activity-recognition."""
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):
        super().__init__()

        # Extract features, 1D conv layers
        self.layer_1   = nn.Conv1d(input_size, 100, 10, stride=1)
        self.activation_relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.layer_2 = nn.Conv1d(100, 100, 10, stride=1)
        self.layer_3 = nn.Conv1d(100, 100, 10, stride=1)
        self.layer_4 = nn.MaxPool1d(2, stride=3)
        self.layer_5 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.layer_6 = nn.Conv1d(100, 160, 10, stride=1)
        self.layer_7 = nn.Conv1d(160, 160, 10, stride=1)
        self.layer_8 = nn.Conv1d(160, 160, 10, stride=1)
#         self.layer_9 = nn.AvgPool1d(97)
        self.layer_10 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.layer_11 = nn.Linear(160, 6)
        self.activation_softmax = nn.Softmax()


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer_1(x)
        x = self.activation_relu(x)
        x = self.layer_2(x)
        x = self.activation_relu(x)
        x = self.layer_3(x)
        x = self.activation_relu(x)
        x = self.layer_4(x)
        x = self.layer_5(x)
        x = self.layer_6(x)
        x = self.activation_relu(x)
        x = self.layer_7(x)
        x = self.activation_relu(x)
        x = self.layer_8(x)
        x = self.activation_relu(x)
        self.layer_9 = nn.AvgPool1d(x.shape[2])
        x = self.layer_9(x)
        x = self.layer_10(x)
        y = self.layer_11(x.view(x.shape[0],x.shape[1]))
        # y = self.activation_softmax(y)
        return y
    
    def calculate_accuracy(self, X,y):
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model.forward(X.float())
            max_index = output.max(dim = 1)[1]
            true_output = y.type(torch.LongTensor)
            result =  (max_index == true_output).sum()/y.shape[0]
        return result.detach().numpy()
    
    def calculate_loss(self, X,y, crit):
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model.forward(X.float())
            max_index = output.max(dim = 1)[1]
            true_output = y.type(torch.LongTensor)
            
        return crit(output, true_output).item()
```

Here is the dataset class:

```py
class IMU_dataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self):

        
        self.n = X.shape[0]
        self.x_data = torch.from_numpy(X.reshape(-1,3,400)) 
        self.y_data = torch.from_numpy(y) 

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n
```

EDIT 1:

- I got to know that I need to remove the softmax layer
- I have tried with a lower learning rate and still have the same problem.

Comment: Don't use a softmax along with `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, it already contains a logsoftmax: you should input logits into your criterion.

Comment: Along with what @Ivan has said (which is probably the main problem), your optimizer has an exceptionally large learning rate imo.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I have updated the learning rate as suggested by @OmarAlSuwaidi and the last layer as suggested by ivan. Still the loss and the accuracy is not dropping

Comment: @PrakyathKantharaju How are you not getting an error when performing this: ```x.view(x.shape[0],x.shape[1])```?

Comment: The output of layer 10 is in shape (N, 97, 1); I am removing the last 3rd dimension. I could have reshaped the data, but I thought that would add to the computation graph. So decided to use the view function instead. @OmarAlSuwaidi